# MySQL: Weird log message in the slow queries log

Tags: mysql

I found in the slow queries log there are a bunch of these logs, what exactly does it mean? It looks like mysql is keep restarting itself? I'm using mysql 5.0.77. Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks!

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.0.77-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.0.77-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/libexec/mysqld, Version: 5.0.77-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens in two situations. Something executed a [FLUSH LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html) statement which causes mysqld to close and reopen all logs, including the slow log.

Alternatively, something sent a `SIGHUP` signal to mysqld. This too causes mysqld to close and reopen logs. A `SIGHUP` is commonly sent by [logrotate](https://iain.cx/src/logrotate/) when it performs log rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening is that your log rotation process is asking mysql to start new logs, but it isn't actually rotating the slow query log to a new file.  This could be because  it is set to a minimum log size or just doesn't know about the file. The MySQL docs have [some information about log rotation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/log-file-maintenance.html), but most distributions use a systemwide tool to handle all the rotation for all the different servers and logs at once.  For instance, Debian uses `logrotate` which is configured with the list of mysql log files in `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server`